# mypy complains about list of tuples when the tuple element types are defined

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

I have this code:

```py
def foo(data: list[tuple[int, ...]]) -> None:
    pass


r = [(1, 2, 3)]
foo(r)
```

Checking with `mypy 1.8.0` results in an error:

```
main.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "list[tuple[int, int, int]]"; expected "list[tuple[int, ...]]"  [arg-type]
main.py:6: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
main.py:6: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I would expect that type `list[tuple[int, int, int]]` would match a type hint defined as `list[tuple[int, ...]]`

Interestingly enough, it works if it is not inside a list:

```py
def foo(data: tuple[int, ...]) -> None:
    pass


r = (1, 2, 3)
foo(r)
```

Results in:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

It also works if I use a `Sequence` type instead of `list`:

```py
from typing import Sequence

def foo(data: Sequence[tuple[int, ...]]) -> None:
    pass


r = [(1, 2, 3)]
foo(r)
```

Results in:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Why does mypy yield an error when using a `list` (or `typing.List`) in this case?

Comment: What if you do `r = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5)]` so the nested tuples don't have a constent type?

Comment: Yes, because lists are invariant, did you read the link it suggested? Did you try with `Sequence`?

Comment: Lists are invariant, sequences are not. (The issue is the type checker doesn't know you won't try to *add* an arbitrary tuple to the argument of the function, which could violate the static type. Sequences are read-only, so they can be covariant like you expect.)